# Connecting a medium sized 1 kVA Inverter with a 2 kVA Generator

Tags: solar-cell, generator, converter, dc-ac

I have a 1 kVA inverter which is using a 12 V battery to generate 220 V AC (battery is connected to a charge controller and is being charged by a PV). In addition I've got a 2 kVA generator.

According to load consumption of power, is there a concept or a design or even a name for a circuit that can smartly switch between the two sources to provide power for the load at any given time? I'll explain further:

If the PV is partially shadowed i.e maximum power of the PV system can not be obtained, is there a circuit that can instantly respond to this change and supply the load from the generator? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No ...you cannot instantly change from an invertor to a generator.
The generator will take time to start and stabilize. It will also start providing voltage output at a low frequency (it may reach target voltage at only 30-40 Hz) and may be above frequency as it finally reaches low load running speed. The best you could achieve is probably around 4-5 seconds.

If you have batteries being charged on the PV array, then it would appear you won't lose the invertor for at least some time, so I'm not sure you ever need 'instant' transfer.

There are many schemas for controlling changeover/transfer from Invertor to generator and you would be best to consider a commercial and fully debugged system for this. This is not a DIY roll-your-own project unless you have exceptional skills.

Look online for automated transfer switches for PV and generator, there are many.

However if you want a simpler solution and your Invertor can supply all the house power you need (in other words you don't need the generator to supply more power than your invertor at times), you could try this.....

If you put a battery charger on the generator (if your batteries are 12 V then you are looking for a 75-100 A charger to make this worthwhile), and connect this to your batteries being charged by the PV array, you can charge the batteries with PV OR generator power OR both.
Now the task of deciding when to start the generator is easy, you simply put a voltage/current monitor on the PV array or simple voltage monitor on the battery.
With a 75-100 A charger, your generator should be able to fully charge the batteries in just a couple of hours.
Now you have a no-break system since it's on Invertor power all the time. When the generator starts it's simply replacing the power that would come from the PV array so no complicated transfer switch.
There are multiple commercial solutions that achieve this sort of configuration, you could look for systems for RV's such as this Xantrex [model](http://www.xantrex.com/power-products/default/automatic-generator-start.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe my description was not clear enough as I said the generator is providing 220V Ac and no start up for the generator is required at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a microgrid. It is not a circuit, but a system of coordinated pieces of power conversion and control equipment. A variety of microgrids have been proposed, designed, implemented and described in published literature. Societies within the Institute of Electrical and Electronic Engineers (IEEE) regularly publish technical papers about microgrids. In the USA, the U.S. Department of Energy, National Laboratories and research organizations have information about micro grids on their web sites.

This is a whole field of study, not a simple question and answer issue.

Some of the U.S. Government sites have beginning level material on their sites. There is likely do-it-yourself type information on DIY and home energy project sites. Some vendors my have "plug and play" products and offer guidance for micro grids. There is likely a way to do what you want with the performance that you want, but it is going to require some searching and study.

Comment: I do agree with this essentially being a microgrid, but I think you're overdramatizing. OP just needs an intermediate circuit fed from battery, PV and generator, stabilized by enough capacity to allow the combustion motor to spin up should the voltage of said circuit fall. Most generator systems, in fact, have such a intermediate circuit internally. So all OP needs to do is connect his PV & battery to the intermediate circuit of the generator. That, I agree, is certainly non-trivial, but it's not "bleeding edge research", either.

Comment: @Marcus Muller: I think that the "instantly respond" aspect pushes the complexity up a bit. I certainly don't recommend starting by reading "bleeding edge research" papers, but I don't want to try to recommend anything specific. I will revise my answer.

Comment: The two of us will probably agree on "instantaneous" being << period of the inverter output, but I don't think that what OP had in mind. As said, sufficient capacitive buffering of an intermediate circuit is probably key, here.